# Building programs which run without extra dlls of MinGW and MSYS

Tags: mingw, msys

I build some fortran programs with gfortran under MinGW and MSYS on my Windows 7. But When I run them on other computers on which MinGW and MSYS are not installed, the system always asks for some dlls like libgfortran-3.dll or libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll.

I wanna ask if there is a way to build programs which run without extra dlls of MinGW and MSYS. I've heard there is an option for cygwin users, namly '-mno-cygwin', which makes the programs running without cygwin1.dll. Is there a similar option for MinGW and MSYS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**MinGW-w64 project**](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net) will create 32-bit and 64-bit apps, that are static.

That is to say, they do not require external dlls.

Comment: +1 for a succinct answer where one suffices. :) (and, ditto @user2348979 :D)

Answer (score 1):

You can install MinGW-w64 via [Cygwin setup](https://cygwin.com/) and use the `-static` command-line option to avoid the dependency on `libgfortran-3.dll`. E.g.

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gfortran -o hello.exe -Wall -static hello.f
```